How to render JSON output from a Sling Model in HTL (AEM)(CQ)?
I want to render the JSON output produced by the getJson() method in an HTL file (mycomponent.html). The goal is to call the getJson() method inside HTL, which will output the serialized JSON string into the HTML content of the page.
I have created a custom component in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) using Sling Models. The goal of the component is to render the JSON output of the content from your Sling Model directly in the HTL (HTML Template Language) for display in the frontend.
This is My Sling Model-
@Model(adaptables = {Resource.class, SlingHttpServletRequest.class}, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL,
        resourceType = "/apps/projecte/components/mycomponent")
@Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json", selector = "karthik", options = {
        @ExporterOption(name = "SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE", value = "true")
})
@JsonRootName("karthikeya Reddy")
public class Mycomponent {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mycomponent.class);

    @ValueMapValue
    private String firstName;

    @ValueMapValue
    private String lastName;

    @ValueMapValue
    private String rollNumber;

    @ValueMapValue
    private String image;

    @ValueMapValue
    private String subscribe;

    @ValueMapValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private String country;

    @ChildResource
    private List<Mycomponentchild> multi;

    // Getter methods
    public List<Mycomponentchild> getMulti() {
        return multi;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getSubscribe() {
        return subscribe;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String str = "";
        try {
            // Serialize the object to JSON
            str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);
            logger.info("Serialized JSON: {}", str); // Log the JSON output
        
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("Error serializing Mycomponent: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return str;
    }
}

I have created a Sling Model for my AEM component (Mycomponent) that serializes an object into JSON. However, I'm unable to figure out how to call this model's getJson() method in the HTL to display the JSON output on the component. Can you help me with the correct HTL syntax or suggest any changes to the code to achieve this?

What have you tried so far and how has it not been working? Share the code for your HTL and the desired and rendered output.



${myComponent.json}

By using the above HTL code i have called the sling Model in  my component
and the output is Blank
Is the output completely blank or are the <div> and <pre> tags getting rendered, albeit empty? If it’s the latter, try returning a static string in the getJson method and check whether that gets output.

@KarthikeyaReddy Don't post code into comment section. Edit your question instead. You can doing it so by click on Edit link underneath your question.
